# GWT hosted mode very slow

Tags: eclipse, gwt, mode, hosted

We do have problems with GWT hosted mode running in Eclipse Ganymede (Windwos XP 3GB RAM). When we start our application in hosted mode it takes very long to start and also the transactions once the application is started are taking minutes to react. It seems as if it takes very long to communicate between Javascript and server.

The processor shows almost no load during this time. Even compiling and starting from an external browser does not help.

Strange is that we do have two other computers (one Windows XP one Linux) with exact the same setup where the hosted mode is working at normal speed without any problems for the same application.

Answer (score 4):

Do yourself a favour, move to GWT 2.0 (currently in RC2) and take advantage of Out Of Process Hosted Mode (OOPHM), which lets you debug straight in the browser, and is lightning fast!

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UsingOOPHM

Comment: It is slow too for loading and connecting to the browser in my machine it takes up to 20 seconds and after that it is ok, but every refresh takes the same time

Answer (score 4):

Try removing all breakpoints. It helped me in such a scenario. Apparently if you place breakpoints in critical points in the program, it can cause everything to grind to nearly a halt in hosted mode.

Answer (score 3):

I second the suggestion to switch to GWT 2. Please note, however, that with GWT 2, hosted mode is very slow in Chrome. I recently switched from 1.7 to 2.0 and found hosted mode to be very slow ... until I switched to Firefox. Reason for this is that Chrome's process model is not benificial to OOPHM, at least now.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Does the slow Windows box have a heavily fragmented hard-drive?
- Is it a specific database query that's taking a long time once the application is running, or are all interactions slow?
- Are the project files on a local filesystem?
- Is the database on a local filesystem?

  - If so, does it have the same size data set as the other machines?
  - If not, are they on different subnets or have different bandwidth available?