# Eclipse and Google plugin (gwt) very slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, gwt

I use Eclipse and GWT plugin.

I've got a medium project (about 500 files). When I save a file, it can be fast or takes a long long time (about 1 to 2 minutes). The problem is that now, it often takes long time to save.

The message in progress bar is "refreshing reference" and there is dozens of tasks "refreshing reference".

I don't know how to solve it...

Have you got an idea why eclipse is so slow and indicates dozens of "refreshing reference" tasks when it happens.

I precise I've got a good computer : 4Go RAM, double core Mac Book Pro 15" disk 7200

**EDIT: I confirmed it's come from google plugin eclipse. When I uninstall it, it runs perfectly. I think that this plugin has some bugs...

A thread has been started on GWT mailing list.

An issue has been opened: star it if you have same problems: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5773
**

Comment: Try first an optimized `eclipse.ini` to see if the problem persists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Comment: this does not fixed my problem, there is always "refreshing reference" message again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a performance bug.

Google team works on it and you can follow it here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5773

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that have caused severe slowness in Eclipse for me:

- Having a large type hierarchy open in the "Type Hierarchy" view. This makes saving all files which are in the hierarchy extremely slow. Use "Clear history" on that view. A similar (though lesser) effect can also be caused by the "Search results" and similar views.
- Remove all AspectJ integration, if possible. Similar with Spring integration (Springsource Tool Suite). These solutions cause a very significant slowdown.
- Content assist: In "Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced": Remove all checkmarks on "Java (Task focused)", and replace them with just "Java". This improves content assist speed by a multiple.

As always, use high enough memory settings in the eclipse.ini.
Also, on the Mac, it's a good idea to use a current Cocoa version of Eclipse.

Comment: I do not use the hierarchy view, I've deleted all Springsource tool Suite and I've check only two checkboxes (non tasks focused) for content assist. The problem stays the same

Comment: @Jerome: Well, there can certainly be lots of other reasons. Do you see the problem only when working with this specific workspace, or with other workspaces, too? Could you try to check out your project(s) into a new workspace?

Comment: @Jerome: "that does not run", "this does not fix[ed] my problem", ... These are really *quite* unfriendly responses, I must say. This isn't (paid) user support, we're not here to *fix* your problem. All we can give you (free of charge) is a few suggestions from experience, which have helped in the past, and which may or may not help in your situation.

Comment: Sorry for that, I was not thinking my answer was unfriendly and if this is the case, I really apologize. My english is not really fluent so in some circumstances, I don't understand the impact of some words. I really appreciate your help and thank you for your comment ! For the problem, I wrote the same in the GWT mailing list and a google team member detects the same issue. So GWT team will investigate. I keep you informed.

Comment: @Jerome: Thanks for clarifying. I found your new [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5773) and your [post on the gwt group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/google-web-toolkit/z--w8uEgOHE) - it seems there's a real (new?) problem with GPE. Haven't encountered that one yet, but I'll definitely star the issue.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a real problem. So, wait and see ;)

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to check is to remove GWT breakpoints (see [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137370/1034782)).
I was using GWT debug mode since a long time, and one day, compile + load took from 1min to 15min.

Removing the green (C) class breakpoint was THE trick for me.